# Fetching names of StringEnum

Tags: fable-f#

Is there a way to fetch all cases for a `StringEnum` in Fable?

If I were using dotnet, I might do something like this:

```ml
 FSharpType.GetUnionCases(t, true)
      |> Array.map(fun i ->
        i.GetCustomAttributes ()
        |> Array.tryPick (function
        | :? CompiledNameAttribute as att -> Some att.CompiledName
        | _ -> None)
        |> Option.defaultWith (fun () -> i.Name)
        |> fun name ->
          let ctor = FSharpValue.PreComputeUnionConstructor i
          let inst = ctor [||]
          (name, inst))
```

However, I can't use that method in Fable. (I can't type test.) What's my alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fable supports a limited subset of the .NET reflection API.

Perhaps this works for your use-case?

```ml
open System
open System.Reflection
open FSharp.Reflection

type Fruit =
| Apple
| Banana
| Cherry

let unionCases (t : Type) =
  [
    for uci in FSharpType.GetUnionCases(t, true) do
      let name = uci.Name
      let value = FSharpValue.MakeUnion(uci, [||])

      name, value
  ]

for name, value in unionCases typeof<Fruit> do
    printfn "\"%s\" -> %A" name value
```

Output

```
"Apple" -> Apple 
"Banana" -> Banana 
"Cherry" -> Cherry
```